# How to create image and push image to docker hub

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, microservices

I want to push my microservice to dockerhub but i dont know how to push it to docker hub, after `docker login` 
then im `using docker push`  then its go this message

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/microservicehelloworld]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: microservicehelloworld
```

and then im using

```
docker tag microservicehelloworld  microservicehelloworld
```

and it shows error message like this

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: microservicehelloworld:latest
```

here is my full solution, is there any file missing , or something that i must do to create docker image ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Please create your account in hub.docker.com. , with your user name.

Step 2 : Build your image locally using your Dockerfile
        `$ docker build -t="mysql_mac" -f mysql_dockerfile .`,In these case my image name is `mysql_mac`

Step 3 : It will create the image called mysql_mac and now tag it and push to hub.docker.com

Step 4 : `$ docker tag mysql_mac aamir2292/mysql_mac`. **Note** my login name is `aamir2292` on docker-hub.

Step 5 : `$ docker push aamir2292/mysql_mac`

**Congrats You have created a mysql image.**

Answer (score 0):

Inside the directory where you've got the Dockerfile you will need to do a build like:

```
docker build -t microservicehelloworld .
```

and then tag is as follows:

```
docker tag microservicehelloworld docker.io/library/microservicehelloworld
```

and finally you will be able to push it:

```
docker push docker.io/library/microservicehelloworld
```